# Reading from text file and then store the item into a list

Tags: c++

Im trying to read from a file called `stock.txt`, which contains the following values:

**ID, Item, Colour, Size, Quantity, Price**

```
11,T-shirt,blue,XL,2,10.500000
12,Supreme,red,M,10,20.500000
13,BANG,red,M,10,20.500000
```

I wanted to store each item in a list, how can I do that?

```
int main() {
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("Stock.txt");

        string id; string title; string colour; string size; string quantity; string cost;

        //If file open is successful
        while(infile.good()){
            getline(infile,id,',');
            getline(infile,title,',');
            getline(infile,colour,',');
            getline(infile,size,',');
            getline(infile,quantity,',');
            getline(infile,cost,'\n');        
        }

        infile.close();
}
```

Comment: *I wanted to store each item in a list, how can I do that?* -- What type of list?  Please be more specific.

Comment: So I wanted to store every line into a vector

Comment: Please add the `struct` or `class` you will be inputting the information into.

Comment: Added @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: I thought you were reading the items into a `struct` or `class`, not in local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should model each row with a `class` or `struct`:

```
struct Record
{
    int id;
    std::string title;
    std::string colour;
    std::string size;
    int quantity;
    double price;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record & r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record & r)
{
    char comma;
    input >> r.id;
    input >> comma;
    std::getline(input, r.title, ',');
    std::getline(input, r.colour, ',');
    std::getline(input, r.size, ',');
    input >> r.quantity;
    input >> comma;
    input >> r.price;
    input.ignore(100000, '\n');
    return input;
}
```

Now you can read into a list:

```
std::list<Record> database;
Record r;
while (infile >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

The overloading of `operator>>` makes the code simpler and easier to read.

Comment: Because price is of type `float`, the line `input >> r.price` gives back an error. And the `while (infile >> r)` gives me back this message: `Use of overloaded operator '>>' is ambiguous`

Comment: The parameter `Record r` for the `operator>>` function should be `Record& r`, passing by reference.

Comment: got it, if `price` is of type `float`, can I not use `input >> r.price` ? Why is it giving me an error

Comment: I ran the above code and had no problems.  Floating point can be represented in C++ as either `float` or `double`.  The `double` has greater precision (and most libraries use `double`.  Use a debugger and find out.

Comment: Must be elsewhere in your code.  My code doesn't have the word `float` in it.

Comment: Ohh so in your code is `double price;` mine is actually of type `float price`

Comment: Nvm, its a small typo my bad.

Comment: I was wondering, now that the file is read and the content is stored into the list `database` if I were to search for specific items (say with the ID), I can just search from this list right?

Comment: You would need to use `std::find` with a custom comparison object or function.  You'll have to search the internet for "std::find custom comparison" to find out how.  Too big to describe in the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a more moden C++ approach.

I would be happy, if you could study this solution and try to use some features in the future.

In the object orient world, we use classes (or structs) and put data and functions, operating on this data, in one (encapsulated) object.

Only the class should know, how to read and write its data. Not some outside global functions. Therefor I added 2 member functions to your struct. I have overwritten the inserter and the extractor operator.

And in the extractor, we will use modern C++ algorithms, to split a string into tokens. For this purpose, we have the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. And because there is a specialized function for this purpose, we should use it. And besides, it is ultra simple.

With the below one-liner, we split the complete string into tokens and put the resulting tokens in a `std::vector`

```
std::vector token(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), delimiter, -1), {});
```

Then we copy the resulting data in our member variables.

For demo output I have also overwritten the inserter operator. Now you can use the exteractor and inserter operators (">>" and "<<") for variables of type Stock, as for any other C++ integral variable.

In main, we use also an ultrasimple approach. First, we open the file and check, if this was OK.

Then we define a variable "stocks" (A `std::vector` of Stock) and use its range constructor and the `std::istream_operator` to read the complete file. And, since the App has an overwritten extractor operator, it knows, how to read and will parse the complete CSV file for us.

Again, the very simple and short one-liner

```
std::vector stocks(std::istream_iterator<Stock>(inFile), {});
```

will read the complete source file, all lines, parse the lines and store the member variables in the single stock elements of the resulting `std::vector`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


std::regex delimiter{ "," };

struct Stock {
    // The data. Member variables
    std::string id{};
    std::string title{};
    std::string colour{};
    std::string size{};
    std::string quantity{};
    std::string cost{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Stock& s) {

        // Read a complete line
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {
            // Tokenize it
            std::vector token(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), delimiter, -1), {});
            // If we read at least 6 tokens then assign the values to our struct
            if (6U <= token.size()) {
                // Now copy the data from the vector to our members
                s.id = token[0];
                s.title = token[1];
                s.colour = token[2];
                s.size = token[3];
                s.quantity = token[4];
                s.cost = token[5];
            }

        }
        return is;
    }

    // Overwrite inserter operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Stock& s) {
        return os << "ID: " << s.id << "\nTitle: " << s.colour
            << "\nSize:   " << s.size << "\nQuantity:  " << s.quantity << "\nCost: " << s.cost;
    }
};

int main() {

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inFile("stock.txt"); inFile) {

        // Define the variable and use range constructor to read and parse the complete file
        std::vector stocks(std::istream_iterator<Stock>(inFile), {});

        // Show result to the user
        std::copy(stocks.begin(), stocks.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Stock>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note: I am using C++17 and can define the std::vector without template argument. The compiler can deduce the argument from the given function parameters. This feature is called CTAD ("class template argument deduction").

Additionally, you can see that I do not use the "end()"-iterator explicitely.

This iterator will be constructed from the empty brace-enclosed initializer list with the correct type, because it will be deduced to be the same as the type of the first argument due to the std::vector constructor requiring that.

Comment: Thankyou for writing this. I really appreciate it

Comment: so Ive just looked over ur code and its kind of difficult for me to understand, Im still a newbie. Is there maybe a simpler way to just read from the file and put it into the vector? The goal for me is to do just that and afterwards I want to make a function which allows user to search for a specific item in that vector (for example with ID / title of the item)